# Unnecessary comma in enum declaration

Tags: c#, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET Enumeration allows comma in the last field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147333/net-enumeration-allows-comma-in-the-last-field)

```
public enum SubPackageBackupModes
{
    Required,
    NotRequired //no comma
}

public enum SubPackageBackupModes
{
    Required,
    NotRequired, //extra unnecessary comma 
}
```

Since both compile, is there any differences between these declarations?

Comment: Nope......................its a convenience thing,  for adding the next and the next....

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792753/is-the-last-comma-in-c-enum-required

Comment: @Greg Treleaven - its not an *exact* duplicate. c != c#

Comment: True, but C# borrows a large portion of its syntax from C. It makes sense that if it's allowed in C99, it would be allowed in C#. A similar rationale applies, in addition to history.

Comment: @Greg: that's link is for `C` not `C#`, that's more suitable --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147333/net-enumeration-allows-comma-in-the-last-field

Comment: @froeschli @digEmAll: Oh, I didn't notice that c# tag.  My mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer second syntax because if you will add addition member to your enum you will have only one line difference in SCM.

Comment: You can also achieve that by putting the comma before the value (i.e. no comma on the first line) -- ugly but can be useful for cases where the extra comma isn't allowed.

Comment: @tdavies, agree, ugly :) I will prefer having two lines of diff instead of lines starting with comma.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no difference.

This was allowed in C++ also, and that continues. I guess it is easier with the comma, since you may comment out the last enum element and it is easier for code-generation tools.