# C# Enum compiler bug/glitch?

Tags: c#, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET Enumeration allows comma in the last field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147333/net-enumeration-allows-comma-in-the-last-field)

i noticed while i was refreshing my memory on c# that with enums, you dont get a complaint from the compiler when you leave a comma after the last variable... EG

```
enum fruit {
    apple,
    pear,
    watermelon,
}
```

i was wondering you can do this? shouldnt the compiler say "syntax error: ," or something?

Comment: It looks useful to me if there's a possibility you'll be adding more stuff later.  This permits the same syntax on every item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is part of the C# specification, the compiler is simply following it.

Document: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf
Page 363, Section 19.7

Comment: That's a **big** document to comb through to find a single sentence.

Comment: Pdf Page 363/Doc Page 341/Section 19.7

Comment: @spender I know; the accepted answer to the linked duplicate question says so. This answer (which was likely cribbed from the link anyway) does not.

Comment: @dlev, I've updated my answer to specify the page and section.

Comment: righto, thanks heaps. i thought i was going mad haha