# Why NameValueCollection instance initialization still compiles with extra comma?

Tags: c#, namevaluecollection

I am using `NameValueCollection` to store values that I will post to API server later. Today I accidentally added extra comma when I initialize an instance of `NameValueCollection` like simple code below:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection()
{
    ["foo"] = "bar",
    ["hello"] = "world", // <-- an extra comma here
};
```

Note that there is extra comma after `world` value. This code compiles normally on my computer and other dev's computer, with or without extra comma. But I can't manage it to run on [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/131Nvm) even using the right code. I'm using .NET 4.6.1 if it matters.

I am aware of different way to initialize `NameValueCollection` like on fiddle above, but it's not the problem/question. My question is, why can the compiler compile this broken code and not issue some warning? Or maybe my Visual Studio settings are incorrect in somewhere? Or I am missing some coding principle? Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: It’s valid C# - 7 something?. Have a ‘fiddle’ link? Maybe it’s using an older C# language target (6? earlier 7?) that does support the “assignment” syntax (and *naught* with the trailing comma).

Comment: @user2864740 I think I'm using C# 6, since the installed .NET on my computer is 4.6.1. Fiddle link is provided on the question, or please visit this [https://dotnetfiddle.net/131Nvm] (link).

Comment: [Don't confuse .NET Framework versions with C# versions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/247621/8967612).

Comment: That dictonary initializer is available from C#6. The .Net Framework is not related to the C# version. The comma appended to the last element is ignored.

Comment: @peter-duninho, Oops, I didn't find the question. Thank you for pointing me.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is not specific to NameValueCollection, all collection types as well as `Enum`s allow this.
2. This has got nothing to do with .NET Framework version. This is a C# compiler feature.
3. This makes programmer's life easier. If you get a chance to work in PHP/JS, this feels like a welcome little feature.
4. You can read more details about it in [this excellent SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147333/net-enumeration-allows-comma-in-the-last-field).